# linux + at command + how to kill the job

Tags: linux, bash, at

I use the at command in order to run the task (test script ) every one min

```
 at -f /tmp/test now +1 minute
 commands will be executed using /bin/tcsh
 job 1438153690.a at Wed Jul 29 10:08:10 2015
```

but how to kill this Job? ( 1438153690.a ) If needed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before it starts running, use `atrm` to remove the job from the queue; afterwards, use `kill`.

By the way, `at` won't run it every minute, as your question appears to suppose; it will run it once, in 60s time.  To run it every minute, use `cron`.